# Android DateFormat for AM/PM differs between devices

Tags: java, android, date-format, simpledateformat, android-date

I am formatting dates like this:

```
    public static String toFormattedDate(@NonNull Time time, String toFormat) {
        mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);

        Date date = new Date();
        date.setTime(time.toMillis(true));

        return mDateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

and the format I am using is:

```
    public static final String TIME = "hh:mm a";
```

But it differs between the two devices that I am using for testing...

Nexus 10:
[image: Nexus 10]

Nexus 5X:
[image: Nexus 5X]

How can I format it uniformly between devices?

Comment: For a workaround, I just used String.replace("a.m.", "AM").replace("p.m.", "PM") but I wonder if I can already fix this through formatting and not String manipulation.

Comment: change that date value to `UPPER CASE` while setting to view.

Comment: @skadoosh already did that. I followed the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may either have to use either the 24 hour value to determine what to append so that you can add the format you desire.

```
public static final String TIME = "hh:mm";
```

and then

```
String ampm = Integer.parseInt(time.valueOf("hh")) >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
...
return mDateFormat.format(date)+" "+ampm;
```

Or if you feel lazy you can just do without changing the value of TIME:

```
return mDateFormat.format(date).toUpperCase().replace(".","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: It still differs between Nexus 10 and Nexus 5X. Nexus 10 formats it to "AM" or "PM" while Nexus 5X formats it to "a.m." or "p.m.". I guess I would just have to manually format this.

Comment: "AM" and "a.m" are related to system configuration so you can do it manually to show either in "AM" or "a.m", but it is not recommended